# How to prevent an XmlException when creating a valid ServerDocument instance?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, vsto, wordprocessingml

I have the following code:

```
var sd = new ServerDocument(documentPath);
```

It should be noted that documentPath is a valid path and that the document uses a vsto application. It opens nicely in word and I can use my vsto extension without any problems.

The mentioned line of code throws an Exception:

> Root element is missing.
>
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.OfficeOpenXmlAppInfoDocument.ServerAppInfo.TryGetManifestInfo(PackagePart
>   part, ManifestType& type, String& xml)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.OfficeOpenXmlAppInfoDocument.ServerAppInfo.EnsureMaps()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.OfficeOpenXmlAppInfoDocument.ServerAppInfo..ctor(Package
>   package)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.OfficeOpenXmlAppInfoDocument.EnsureAppInfo()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.OfficeOpenXmlAppInfoDocument.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.IAppInfo.ReadItem(String
>   type, String id)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AppInfo.GetDeploymentManifestUrl(IAppInfo
>   appInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.Initialize(Byte[]
>   bytes, String documentPathOrFileType, FileAccess access, Boolean
>   throwOnPreviousVersion)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.Initialize(Byte[]
>   bytes, String documentPathOrFileType, FileAccess access)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument..ctor(String
>   documentPath)    at ConsoleApplication12.Program.Main(String[] args)

How to prevent this problem?

Comment: Please note that documentPath is a valid docx file.

Comment: Are you using ServerDocument with the same version of VSTO as used to create the document? I get the impression that ServerDocument isn't finding the content it expects... In a Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Does your document have a root element?

The error you're getting:

> "Root element is missing."

indicates that your document is, well, missing a root element. So what's a "root element"?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) says:

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements.

Here's an example:

```
<animals>
    <cat />
    <dog />
    <armadillo />
</animals>
```

`animals` is the root element in this example.

In short - check your document to make sure it has one, and only one, root element.

Comment: The docx is not an xml file that can miss a root. It is a zip file containing multiple xml's. The docx itself is valid. I think it is dangerous to modfiy a valid docx. I want to fix something that is not working instead of possibly breaking something that is working.

Comment: Is it possible one of the XML files in the .docx file is missing a root element, or even empty? This despite the .docx opening well in other apps?

Comment: Sure, but changing/deleting them makes the docx invalid.